# Kivy Buildozer: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

i am testing Kivy with Buildozer to make an small app for my Android Device. On my PC everythink is running correctly. But when i want to create the APK with Buildozer everytime i get the Error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

I googled a lot of times, but i could not find an answer to my question.

Does anyone has a hint for me?

Would be great.

Thank You!

main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput  
import random
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import requests
import json

def login (name,password):
    url_login = 'URL'
    payload = {'email': name, 'password': password}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url_login, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
    return (r['token'])
token =login("ID","PW")

class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    oee = ObjectProperty(None)
    performance = ObjectProperty(None)
    quality = ObjectProperty(None)
    availability = ObjectProperty(None)
    sensorstandort = ObjectProperty(None)
    schicht = ObjectProperty(None)
    timestamp = ObjectProperty(None)
    alert = ObjectProperty(None)

    def oee_anzeige(self, *args):
        #Anfrage an Server senden
        url_report = 'URL/'
        payload_report = {}
        headers_report = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token}
        r_report = requests.get(url_report, data=json.dumps(payload_report), headers=headers_report)
        response = r_report.json()

        #Schicht, Sensorstandort und ggfs. Störgrund raussuchen
        x = 0
        for i in response['included']:
            if response['included'][x]['type'] == 'shift':
                schicht = response['included'][x]['attributes']['name']
            if response['included'][x]['type'] == 'location':
                sensorstandort = response['included'][x]['attributes']['name']
            if response['included'][x]['type'] == 'notification':

                timestamp = str(response['included'][x]['attributes']['inserted-at'])
                timestamp = timestamp[11:16] + ' Uhr'

                #self.timestamp.text = timestamp
                if response['included'][x]['attributes']['triggered-by'] == 'standstill':
                    self.alert.text = "Verfügbarkeitsverlust seit"
                elif sensorstandort == response['included'][x]['attributes']['triggered-by'] == 'slowdown':
                    self.alert.text = "Leistungsverlust seit"
            x +=1






        #oee Werte aus API ziehen
        oee = str(response['data']['attributes']['oee']) + " %"
        availability = str(response['data']['attributes']['availability']) + " %"
        performance =str(response['data']['attributes']['performance']) + " %"
        quality = str(response['data']['attributes']['quality']) + " %"




        #Labels definieren
        self.oee.text = oee
        self.availability.text = availability
        self.performance.text = performance
        self.quality.text = quality
        self.sensorstandort.text = sensorstandort
        self.schicht.text = schicht


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2  # used for our grid


class EpicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        t = ConnectPage()
        Clock.schedule_once(t.oee_anzeige, 2)
        Clock.schedule_interval(t.oee_anzeige, 90)
        return t



if __name__ == "__main__":
    EpicApp().run()
```

Epic.kv

```
<ConnectPage>:





    oee:oee
    availability: availability
    performance: performance
    quality: quality
    sensorstandort: sensorstandort
    schicht: schicht
    alert: alert
    timestamp: timestamp

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2


        Label:
            text: "wird geladen"
            id: sensorstandort
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "wird geladen"
            id: schicht
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "OEE"
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "wird geladen"
            id: oee
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]



        Label:
            text: "Verfügbarkeit"
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "Wird geladen"
            id: availability
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]



        Label:
            text: "Leistung"
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "Wird geladen"
            id: performance
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]


        Label:
            text: "Qualität"
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "Wird geladen"
            id: quality
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]


        Label:
            text:
            id: alert
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text:
            id: timestamp
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Log from Buildozer Logcat:

```
....
04-01 19:37:22.029 19854 19881 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-01 19:37:22.030 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 97, in <module>
04-01 19:37:22.031 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
04-01 19:37:22.032 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
04-01 19:37:22.034 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
04-01 19:37:22.035 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
04-01 19:37:22.035 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
04-01 19:37:22.036 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
04-01 19:37:22.037 19854 19881 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:37:22.037 19854 19881 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:37:22.038 19854 19881 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:37:22.039 19854 19881 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
04-01 19:37:22.040 19854 19881 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 52, in oee_anzeige
04-01 19:37:22.041 19854 19881 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
04-01 19:37:22.041 19854 19881 I python  : Python for android ended.
....
04-01 19:44:07.500 20768 20788 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-01 19:44:07.501 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 97, in <module>
04-01 19:44:07.502 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
04-01 19:44:07.503 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
04-01 19:44:07.504 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
04-01 19:44:07.504 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
04-01 19:44:07.505 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
04-01 19:44:07.505 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
04-01 19:44:07.506 20768 20788 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:44:07.507 20768 20788 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:44:07.507 20768 20788 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:44:07.508 20768 20788 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
04-01 19:44:07.508 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 52, in oee_anzeige
04-01 19:44:07.509 20768 20788 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
04-01 19:44:07.509 20768 20788 I python  : Python for android ended.
04-01 19:48:13.346 21723 21762 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
04-01 19:48:13.347 21723 21762 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
04-01 19:48:13.347 21723 21762 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
04-01 19:48:13.347 21723 21762 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.oeecloud/files/app
04-01 19:48:13.356 21723 21762 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
04-01 19:48:13.356 21723 21762 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
04-01 19:48:13.356 21723 21762 I python  : calculated paths to be...
04-01 19:48:13.356 21723 21762 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.oeecloud/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.oeecloud/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
04-01 19:48:13.380 21723 21762 I python  : set wchar paths...
04-01 19:48:13.420 21723 21762 I python  : Initialized python
04-01 19:48:13.420 21723 21762 I python  : AND: Init threads
04-01 19:48:13.421 21723 21762 I python  : testing python print redirection
04-01 19:48:13.422 21723 21762 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.oeecloud/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.oeecloud/files/app/...
'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
...
04-01 19:48:16.306 21723 21762 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
04-01 19:48:16.307 21723 21762 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-01 19:48:16.309 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 97, in <module>
04-01 19:48:16.311 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
04-01 19:48:16.312 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
04-01 19:48:16.312 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
04-01 19:48:16.313 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
04-01 19:48:16.314 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
04-01 19:48:16.314 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
04-01 19:48:16.315 21723 21762 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:48:16.315 21723 21762 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:48:16.315 21723 21762 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
04-01 19:48:16.316 21723 21762 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
04-01 19:48:16.316 21723 21762 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 52, in oee_anzeige
04-01 19:48:16.317 21723 21762 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
04-01 19:48:16.317 21723 21762 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code in your .py files is throwing the error

```
 #self.timestamp.text = timestamp
                if response['included'][x]['attributes']['triggered-by'] == 'standstill':
                    self.alert.text = "Verfügbarkeitsverlust seit"
                elif sensorstandort == response['included'][x]['attributes']['triggered-by'] == 'slowdown':
                    self.alert.text = "Leistungsverlust seit"
            x +=1
```

I got this information by looking at the log you posted, which tells that there is an error in `line 52` of `main.py` file

```
04-01 19:44:07.508 20768 20788 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 52, in oee_anzeige
04-01 19:44:07.509 20768 20788 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
04-01 19:44:07.509 20768 20788 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Hi yes thank you. I tried to uncomment this task, but the error still occurs and goes to line 74 "self.oee.text = oee" Something is wrong with the .text i think. But its unusual, that my skript works on my PC

Comment: from what I can see, timestamp, oeee, availability, performace etc are ids for the Labels. So what you need to refer to the specific property of the Widget. For example, you can do oeee.text or oeee.width etc. You cannot refer to the oeee only

Comment: can you explain it a little bit more? I edited the variables to for example "oee_" and do at the end the label operation with self.oee.text = ... but this wasnt the problem :(

Comment: for self.oee.text = oee try with self.ids.oee.text = oee and see if it works out // update the error log and code with the latest information

Comment: Hi Thank you for your fast reply. I changed this and now i get another error

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you for your fast reply.
I changed this things and now i get an new Error

```
attributeerror 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' kivy
```

i googled and edited my super.init to `super(ConnectPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)`
but this error still occurs.

Do you have another tip for me?
Thank you!
The Log says:

> 04-02 19:25:36.760 12173 12330 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   04-02 19:25:36.762 12173 12330 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
>   04-02 19:25:36.764 12173 12330 I python  :  KeyError: 'availability'
>   04-02 19:25:36.765 12173 12330 I python  :
>   04-02 19:25:36.766 12173 12330 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   04-02 19:25:36.766 12173 12330 I python  :
>   04-02 19:25:36.766 12173 12330 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   04-02 19:25:36.767 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 96, in 
>   04-02 19:25:36.768 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
>   04-02 19:25:36.768 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
>   04-02 19:25:36.769 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
>   04-02 19:25:36.770 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
>   04-02 19:25:36.771 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
>   04-02 19:25:36.773 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/oeecloud/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
>   04-02 19:25:36.775 12173 12330 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
>   04-02 19:25:36.777 12173 12330 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
>   04-02 19:25:36.777 12173 12330 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
>   04-02 19:25:36.778 12173 12330 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
>   04-02 19:25:36.779 12173 12330 I python  :    File "/home/julian/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 75, in oee_anzeige
>   04-02 19:25:36.779 12173 12330 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
>   04-02 19:25:36.780 12173 12330 I python  :  AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'
>   04-02 19:25:36.780 12173 12330 I python  : Python for android ended.